# Correct way to check performance of piece of code in C#

Tags: c#, performance, memory, cpu-usage

Just assume I have two pieces of code and I want to check CPU usage and Memory of these codes and compare together, is this a good way to check performance:

```
public class CodeChecker: IDisposable
{


    public PerformanceResult Check(Action<int> codeToTest, int loopLength)
    {

        var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

        stopWatch.Start();

        for(var i = 0; i < loopLength; i++)
        {
            codeToTest.Invoke(i);
        }

        stopWatch.Stop();
        var process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

        var result = new PerformanceResult(stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds, process.PrivateMemorySize64);
        return result;

    }
}

public class PerformanceResult
{
    public long DurationMilliseconds { get; set; }
    public long PrivateMemoryBytes { get; set; }

    public PerformanceResult(long durationMilliseconds, long privateMemoryBytes)
    {
        DurationMilliseconds = durationMilliseconds;
        PrivateMemoryBytes = privateMemoryBytes;
    }


    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Duration: {DurationMilliseconds} - Memory: {PrivateMemoryBytes}";
    }
}
```

And:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Start!");
    int loopLength = 10000000;

    var collection = new Dictionary<int, Target>();


    PerformanceResult result;
    using (var codeChecker = new CodeChecker())
    {
        result = codeChecker.Check((int i) => collection.Add(i, new Target()) , loopLength);
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Dict Performance: {result}");


    var list = new List<Target>();
    using(var codeChecker = new CodeChecker())
    {
        result = codeChecker.Check((int i) => list.Add(new Target()), loopLength);
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"List Performance: {result}");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I'm looking for checking performance programmatically and I want to check piece of code specifically not all the application.

Any suggestion to improve aforementioned code?

And I will open to any suggestion for using free tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lot of factors which may impose a bias into your measurement including CLR and JIT compiler influence, heap state, cold or hot run, overall load in your system, etc. Ideally you need to isolate the pieces of code you'd like to benchmark from each other to exclude mutual impact, benchmark only hot runs, not cold to exclude JIT compilation and other cold run factors and what is most important you need to conduct multiple runs to obtain statistical information as single run can be not representative especially on a system which implies multitasking. Luckily you don't have to do it everything manually - there is great [library](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) for bench-marking which does all things mentioned and much more and which is widely used in various .NET projects.